# How to safely read +-5V with an Arduino

Tags: arduino, negative-voltage

I have a -5V +5V binary signal coming from a CNC controller that I want to read with an Arduino.

This is the way I have it setup:

[image]

The resistors are actually 10K. The left voltage source would be the arduino and the right are the terminals that are either -5V or +5V. The readout in the middle is the digital input pin that now reads 0V for -5V and 5V for 5V.

Is there a difference between:

- One of the terminals being GND with the other being -5V
- GND with 5V but with the terminals flipped.

If there is, how would I even check/measure that since voltmeters just measure the difference in potential?

I've never dealt with negative voltage before so I might have a wrong understanding of it. My worry is that if the latter is the case I'm going to send 5V to GND and fry the board. These are optocoupled signals if that matters.

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: If the signals are optocoupled, how can they be +/- 5V? What signal is that? Some kind of data like RS422 or RS485? Is there ground available?

Comment: Indeed, this doesn't make any sense. Introducing optocouplers would otherwise be one way to convert the signal levels to something in range of your board supply. Please post a schematic of your actual circuit.

Comment: Voltage divider to half that + pull up to 2.5 V midpoint?

Comment: The cnc controller board says the signal are optocoupled (inside the cnc controller) for safety. They're not in my circuit. The oscilloscope reads +5V and -5V depending on the logic state. I'm guessing one of the terminals should be ground. But that's kind of the point of the question. It's not data per se but signal that controls the state of a laser. This is literally my actual circuit unless you want the schematics of the controller board?

Comment: @hellvetica if you have the schematics then you should have posted them already so we don't have to guess how to interface the device. Does the device have a name or manual?

Comment: The controller is an obscure chinese cnc controller called MKX-V XHC and as far as I can tell it has no manual or schematic. There's barely any information about it online. The signal I'm trying to read is the DIR+ and DIR- on the Z axis. I just want to know if it's possible to fry my board if i connect it this way.

Comment: the circuit shown should work fine with 10k's.

Comment: Are you trying to use the isolated spindle output to control a laser?

Comment: Not the spindle output but the Z axis control signal for the stepper motors. I want to use the arduino to convert the signals to the ones the laser likes.

Comment: The signal voltage is likely not negative, but differential (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_signalling). In that case, a negative voltage would appear *between the data lines*. Do a measurement with ground reference and see if you still get negative readings.